# Android Studio Plugin - Show Image In Editor

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc, intellij-plugin

I'd like to be able to display an image below a class-level javadoc in Android Studio. My assumption is that I should write a plugin to make this happen.

Does anyone know what I need to do to get an image (JPEG or PNG) to display below a class-level javadoc comment in a Java class file?

I looked into basic information about creating an IntelliJ IDEA plugin but I have no idea where to look to accomplish my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA. The editor can display only text, and does not support embedding of non-text things such as an image file.

You can display images on hover, or in popups, or in dialogs, but not within the editor itself.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the image to show in the class' source code itself? As an aside, images in Javadocs will show when you view the formatted javadoc view the Quick documentation action (Windows/Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or Mac: <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)

[image]

If you still want the image to show in the source code, then yes, you will need to write a plug-in. You can look at the *Information for Plugin Developers
Setting Up the Plugin Development Environment* section of this web page - https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/plugins - to get started. You'll have to dig through source code to try and find some ideas for how to display an image in the source code. As much as I love IntelliJ IDEA, there plug-in documentation is a bit weak. When I wrote a plug-in, I had to do a lot of looking through the IDEA code to find code that was doing things similar to what I wanted to do. I also downloaded the source code for some of the better plug-ins out there and looked through them.

Finally, you can ask for some guidance in the IntelliJ IDEA [Open API and Plugin Development](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/open_api_and_plugin_development?view=discussions) forum. That forum is monitored by JetBrains developers. Your best bet to getting answers in that forum is to ask very specific questions. Do not try and get someone to explain from start to finish what you need to do. As you do each step, ask questions about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll go ask at the IDEA forum. Do you happen to have any ideas from your own experience where I might stick the image to get in the source code? Do you think that would be within the "Editor" construct or something else?

Comment: @MattC - apparently this is not possible based on yole's answer. "Yole" is a Principal Engineer with JetBrains who was a developer and the tech lead for IntelliJ IDEA for many, many years. So his answer is shall we say rather definitive :)